# Soapclient responds as 'null' but xml response is ok using __getLastResponse

Tags: php, wsdl, soap-client

I'm looking for help with a php soapclient call:

The call is to a remote panel and I want to pull off the log data. There are various services published via the WSDL and I am able to use several with no issues. Here's the list:

```
array(12) { 
[0]=> string(77) "GetGPTimerChannelsResponse GetGPTimerChannels(GetGPTimerChannels     $parameters)" 
[1]=> string(74) "GetGPTimerChannelResponse GetGPTimerChannel(GetGPTimerChannel $parameters)" 
[2]=> string(74) "SetGPTimerChannelResponse SetGPTimerChannel(SetGPTimerChannel $parameters)" 
[3]=> string(47) "GetSlaveResponse GetSlave(GetSlave $parameters)" 
[4]=> string(71) "GetLogDataInlineResponse GetLogDataInline(GetLogDataInline $parameters)" 
[5]=> string(71) "GetLogItemInlineResponse GetLogItemInline(GetLogItemInline $parameters)" 
[6]=> string(59) "GetAlarmListResponse GetAlarmList(GetAlarmList $parameters)" 
[7]=> string(50) "GetSyslogResponse GetSyslog(GetSyslog $parameters)" 
[8]=> string(47) "SetSlaveResponse SetSlave(SetSlave $parameters)" 
[9]=> string(53) "GetVersionResponse GetVersion(GetVersion $parameters)" 
[10]=> string(53) "GetTDBInfoResponse GetTDBInfo(GetTDBInfo $parameters)" 
[11]=> string(53) "GetLogItemResponse GetLogItem(GetLogItem $parameters)" }
```

I am trying to use the GetLogDataInline service which requires four parameters - these I'm passing as an array and all seems OK when doing the connection (the request/response takes around 30 seconds to process).

When I look at a var_dump / print_r of the result, it returns NULL, whereas when I do a call to the __getLastResponse all of the data I need to populate my local database is there.

Below is the code for the soapclient call:

```
$client = new soapclient ("http://192.168.1.126/cgi-bin/cgi.cgi?WSDL", 
array("trace" => 1,
"exceptions" => true,
"cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
"features" => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS
));
$params = array (
        "ResponseType" => "Xml",
        "Step" => 15,
        "Start" => "2012-06-14T12:00:00+01:00",
        "End" => "2012-06-14T23:59:45+01:00"
);  
$result = $client -> GetLogDataInline ($params);
```

An extract from the var_dump / __getLastResponse is:

```
var_dump($client)
object(SoapClient)#1 (4) { ["trace"]=> int(1) ["_features"]=> int(1) ["_soap_version"]=>  int(1) ["sdl"]=> resource(4) of type (Unknown) }

var_dump($result)
NULL

__getLastResponse

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<soap:Envelope  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
<soap:Body> <GetLogDataResponse xmlns="http://url/RDMPlantTDB/2009/03/13/">  
<GetLogDataResult> 
<Step>15</Step> 
<Start>2012-06-14T12:00:00+01:00</Start> 
<End>2012-06-14T23:59:45+01:00</End> 
<LogData>
<![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Data> 
<Fields> <Field>External Temperature</Field> <Field>Workshop Lux Level</Field> <Field>Electricity Pulse 100wh</Field> <Field>Workshop PIR Active</Field> <Field>Boiler Flow Temp</Field> <Field>Outside Lux</Field> <Field>Workshop_Light_Override_Hours</Field> <Field>Water Consumption (Litres)</Field> <Field>Electricity kWh Consumption</Field> <Field>Water Consumption M3</Field> <Field>Gas kWh Consumption</Field> <Field>Outside Lighting</Field> <Field>Heating Effective Setpoint</Field> <Field>Router Reset</Field> <Field>Workshop Lighting State</Field> <Field>Heating Run Hours</Field> <Field>Heating On</Field> <Field>Receptin Percent RH</Field> <Field>Reception Temp</Field> <Field>Reception RH</Field> <Field>Reception Temp</Field> </Fields> 
<Entries> <Entry> <Time>2012-06-14T12:00:00+01:00</Time> <Values> <Value>-85.6</Value> <Value>2.1</Value> <Value>-1.0</Value> <Value>Off</Value> <Value>-91.5</Value> <Value>13.8</Value> <Value>0.0</Value> <Value>-1.0</Value> <Value>0.0</Value> <Value>0.0</Value> <Value>-0.1</Value> <Value>Off</Value> <Value>21.0</Value> <Value>Off</Value> <Value>Off</Value> <Value>0.0</Value> <Value>Off</Value> <Value>53.0</Value> <Value>22.0</Value> <Value>53.0</Value> <Value>22.0</Value> </Values> </Entry> <Entry> <Time>2012-06-14T12:00:15+01:00</Time> <Values> <Value>-85.4</Value> <Value>2.1</Value> <Value>-1.0</Value> <Value>Off</Value> <Value>-91.8</Value> <Value>13.8</Value> <Value>0.0</Value> <Value>-1.0</Value> <Value>0.0</Value> <Value>0.0</Value> <Value>-0.1</Value> <Value>Off</Value> <Value>21.0</Value> <Value>Off</Value> <Value>Off</Value> <Value>0.0</Value> <Value>Off</Value> <Value>53.0</Value> <Value>22.0</Value> <Value>53.0</Value> <Value>22.0</Value> </Values> </Entry> <Entry> <Time>2012-06-14T12:00:30+01:00</Time> <Values> <Value>-85.4</Value> <Value>2.1</Value> <Value>-1.0</Value> <Value>Off</Value> <Value>-91.8</Value> <Value>13.8</Value> <Value>0.0</Value> <Value>-1.0</Value> <Value>0.0</Value> <Value>0.0</Value> <Value>-0.1</Value> <Value>Off</Value> <Value>21.0</Value> <Value>Off</Value> <Value>Off</Value> <Value>0.0</Value> <Value>Off</Value> <Value>53.0</Value> <Value>22.0</Value> <Value>53.0</Value> <Value>22.0</Value> </Values> </Entry> <Entry> <Time>2012-06-14T12:00:45+01:00</Time> <Values> <Value>-85.4</Value> <Value>2.1</Value> <Value>-1.0</Value> <Value>Off</Value> <Value>-91.5</Value> <Value>13.7</Value> <Value>0.0</Value> <Value>-1.0</Value> <Value>0.0</Value> <Value>0.0</Value> <Value>-0.1</Value> <Value>Off</Value> <Value>21.0</Value> <Value>Off</Value> <Value>Off</Value> <Value>0.0</Value> <Value>Off</Value> <Value>54.0</Value> <Value>22.0</Value> <Value>54.0</Value> <Value>22.0</Value> </Values> </Entry> <Entry>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why are you getting NULL but i always use the below method for SOAP client to handle errors (if any).

```
// Calling soap
try{

    // Creating soap server object
    $client     =   new SoapClient("http://192.168.1.126/cgi-bin/cgi.cgi?WSDL");

    // Creating parameters
    $params = array (
        "ResponseType" => "Xml",
        "Step" => 15,
        "Start" => "2012-06-14T12:00:00+01:00",
        "End" => "2012-06-14T23:59:45+01:00"
    );

    // Calling createUser method
    $result     =   $client->__soapCall('METHOD_NAME',$params);

    // Check for a fault
    if (is_soap_fault($client)) {       
        echo '<h2>Fault</h2><pre>';
        print_r($result);
        echo '</pre>';      
    }else{
        echo "Result: <BR><pre>";
        print_r($result);
        echo '</pre>';
    }

}catch(SoapFault $fault){
    $error      =   "SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}\n" ."faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})"; 
    echo $error;
}catch(Exception $exception){
    $error      =   $exception; 
    echo "<BR>".$error;
}
```

In the above example you will have to replace the METHOD_NAME with actual method defined in the soap server to take parameters and return result. But i suspect on the first parameter "ResponseType", is that the actual first parameter expected by the method that handles request?

You can try running above code and see what error occur

I assume that SOAP extension is enabled at the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I've run your code (amending both IP and METHOD and get: 
    'SOAP Fault: (faultcode: soap:Client faultstring: Unknown response type)'. 
I've run the request with the same parameters using soapUI and all works well.
No idea where to go next . . .

Comment: Sorry - SOAP is enabled on the server and using other methods (without parameters) brings back a result object which I'm able to parse with no problems.

Comment: The soapUI documentation extract below might help:

GetLogDataInline
Description:
Returns log information requested.
Operation type:
Request-response. The endpoint receives a message, and sends a correlated message.
SOAP action:
http://[url]/cgi-bin/cgi.cgi?WebService=GetLogDataInline
Input:
GetLogDataInlineSoapIn (soap:body, use = literal)Source code
parameters type GetLogDataInline
ResponseType type ResponseType - type string with restriction - enum { 'Csv', 'Xml' }
Step type int
Start type dateTime
End type dateTime

Comment: I've now implemented a work-around using the nusoap library which returns an array of results. Once parsed using 'simplexml_load_string' it can be manipulated as an array of objects. Whilst it doesn't answer the original question, it does do what I wanted it to do originally.

Comment: Okay, i will also try to find out other way. Thanks for replying back with solution

Answer (score 0):

PHP soapClient doesn't support relative namespaces within SOAP very well, this is usually the cause of this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

if your web services has enabled access permissions, then | new SoapClient - First question? Use public IP public or DNS | $result = $client -> Method($params); - Second question? use private IP, depends on the configuration of DNS

```
$client->__setLocation('http:// youDNSorIPpublic /cgi-bin/cgi.cgi');
var_dump($client);
```

//$old_location = $client->__setLocation(); // disable location
//echo $old_location;

```
$result = $client -> Method($params); //new request
```